# Getting Phonegap app to scale correctly between iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, viewport, phonegap

I am facing an issue with my Phonegap build in that the app I am building is locked into a landscape orientation and built to iPad dimensions (2048x1536px).

When I open the IPA on my iPad, all is fine.

When I open the IPA on my iPhone it scales down to the width of the device, but as the app is locked into landscape orientation, I actually need it to scale to the height of the device. (Sounds easy, right?) I have run through a number of available config and index settings trying to get a solution, but it only gets worse, not better.

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a means to do this. The config has two relevant settings

name="fullscreen"
name="EnableViewportScale"

and the Index HTML, which the app calls on load, offers a generic viewport setting. That is set to  in the version that scales to device width (leaving a portion of the app hanging off the bottom of the screen when held in its required landscape position).

Anyone know a solution? How can I get the html to go "this is in landscape, so I should scale to device height."

Answer (score 0):

Which web framework are you using? I do this in jquery mobile to scale to full screen and it has been full screen whatever the size of my device.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fullscreen.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm exporting out of indesign as an HTML 5 website, then packaging that up with a config.xml file an icon as a zip to upload to Phonegap. 

Unfortunately I am not a coder - hence why I am using indesign and phonegap - so working from a limited understanding of HTML.

Comment: Isn't quite easy to visualize the effect you are trying to achieve. Can you save the codes here and run it as part your of your cordova project to see if it runs in the same "full screen" mode you are seeking? If it does, then this is the code to use. https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_toolbars_fullscreen

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a cordova project. I am using build.phonegap.com directly. The problem is that the app is scaling to the width of the device in landscape mode, On an iPad that is fine, as the app is designed to an iPad's screen resolution. However an iPad is a squarer shape than an iPhone. So when the same app appears on the iphone, it scales to the edge again. This leaves about 1/3 of the app off the bottom edge of the device screen....

Comment: ...What I need it to do is get the device to scale not to the width of the app, but to the height of the app. For the iPhone version, this will create an effect like watching a 4:3 cartoon on a modern TV. You get that letterbox effect on the left and right edges, but at least the bottom of the app won't be off the screen.

Comment: If you pull this set of codes into build.phonegap.com do you get the effect you want? https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_toolbars_fullscreen

Comment: I will see if I can work out how to add it  now. I'm not sure if I understand this code, but it looks like it is for creating a scrollbar. Is this correct?

Comment: It creates a fixed full screen header and footer. The header's will be positioned at the top of the screen, and the footer will stay right at the bottom. So you don't get the 4:3 effect that you were saying. Do click the [^] button if my answer has been somewhat useful. Happy to assist further. :)

Comment: Ah I see, but I need the footer and header to actually be at the left and ride sides of the app. This idea could work though if I can buff out the sides of the app to artificially widen the dimensions. However, I would still need some sort of IF statement as you wouldn't want this effect on iPad, only iPhone. I wish you could put attachments on these comments.

Comment: This will help you to decide if your device is an ipad or iphone. http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/cordova/device/device.model.html#device.model